# Jasmine Tests give error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run Jasmine tests with Karma on my React site. My tests were working before, and I'm not sure what has changed, but now I get the error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

for Chrome and PhantomJS and Firefox give me similar errors. Please let me know if more info would be helpful. I have found a lot of similar questions on the web, but nothing that fixes the problem.

You can see the test file below and the full project is on [my github repo](https://github.com/mrbgit/short-stories/tree/branch).

Thanks in advance!

My test file looks like this:

```js
var React = require('react/addons');
var Story = require('../../app/js/components/story.jsx');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var testUtilsAdditions = require('react-testutils-additions');

  describe('Story component', function () {
    var component;

    beforeEach(function () {
      var element = React.createElement(Story);
      element.props.data = {
        storyTitle: 'front end test title',
        author : 'front end author',
        storyText : 'front end story text'
      };
      component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(element);
      });

    it('should display a story', function () {
      expect(component.props.data).toBeDefined();
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBeDefined();
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBe('front end test title');
      expect(component.props.data.author).toBe('front end author');
      expect(component.props.data.storyText).toBe('front end story text');
    });

  });
```

My karma.conf.js file looks like this:

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jul 02 2015 15:56:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
        'test/karma_tests/*test.js'
    ],

    //plugins to start browsers
    plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-opera-launcher',
    'karma-ie-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-chai',
    'karma-webpack'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'test/karma_tests/*test.js': ['webpack'],
        // 'test/**/*_test.js': ['webpack']
    },

    webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies

            // webpack configuration
        module: {
          loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader:'jsx-loader'
          }]
        }
        },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

This is the error I get after making the changes @guilhebl recommended:

```
Firefox 40.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Module name "react/addons" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /home/michael/repository/short-stories/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:165
```

Here is the karma.conf.js after I made the changes:

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jul 02 2015 15:56:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
    './node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
    './node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js',
    './test/karma_tests/*test.js'
    ],

    //plugins to start browsers
    plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-opera-launcher',
    'karma-ie-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-chai',
    'karma-webpack',
    'karma-requirejs',
    'karma-script-launcher'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'test/karma_tests/*test.js': ['webpack'],
        // 'test/**/*_test.js': ['webpack']
    },

    webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies

            // webpack configuration
        module: {
          loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader:'jsx-loader'
          }]
        }
        },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Comment: It looks like there might be something going on with your webpack build - webpack should define require and make it available to your js files. Did you play around with anything in the webpack settings?

Comment: Thanks theWanderer4865. I haven't done anything to webpack besides build with it. I added my karma.conf.js file to my question so you can see how it's set up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70940235/7186739

Answer (score 1):

You should have require configured in your karma.conf file such as example:

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins : [               
               'karma-chrome-launcher',
               'karma-firefox-launcher',                            
               'karma-script-launcher',
               'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
               'karma-jasmine',
               'karma-requirejs'               
    ],

    files : [          
      'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
      'node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js',      
      'app/js/test-main.js',

      {pattern: 'app/lib/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/js/**/*.js', included: false},      
      {pattern: 'app/js/views/**/*Test.js', included: false}      
    ],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS']        
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks guilhebl. I edited my karma.conf.js to use karma-requirejs and requirejs like you showed, but now I get the error 

``` Uncaught Error: Module name "react/addons" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])```

Comment: @CascadiaJS Can you update your question with this answer's changes you made along with the stacktrace that you get?