# Jasmine Test returns error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

First of all, I know this question has been asked other times, but it seems to be different.

This is my karma config file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jan 21 2016 09:58:23 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/*.js',
      'test/*.js',
      'src/*.js',
      'tests/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

This is my test so far in order to make it work:

```
require('../src/person.js');

describe('Person ', function(){
    it('Should say hi with proposed first name and last name', function() {
        var person = new person();
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

When I run karma I'm getting the error saying `require is not defined`.
How ever, `karma-requirejs` is installed globally by `npm`.

I was reading this question that seems to be the same problem:
[Jasmine Tests give error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130627/jasmine-tests-give-error-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

But after adding

```
plugins : [
    'karma-requirejs',
],
```

to the karma conf file, I have a lot of other errors, that seems it does not recognize this attibute?

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Do you install all of your npm packages globablly?  I'm just curious, because I don't know if that would work.  I would suggest installing `karma-requirejs` in your project's root, or where all of your other npm modules live local to the project.

Comment: It works, now it is being installed in the project root, that was just testing! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70940235/7186739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest installing `karma-requirejs` in your project's root, or where all of your other npm modules live local to the project.